# Error in creating database using EF with a code-first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Path is concatenating with database name

> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\fahidNinjaDomain.DomainModel.NinjaContext.mdf'.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

It should be like this

```
C:\Users\fahid\NinjaDomain.DomainModel.NinjaContext.mdf
```

How can I solve this using `update-database -verbose`?

Comment: There is a "\" missing in the path. It should be "C:\Users\fahid\...", not C:\Users\fahid..."

Answer (score 0):

The missing \ was caused by a bug from Sql Server. See this question for details: [CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884772/create-file-encountered-operating-system-error-5access-is-denied-while-attemp). And download the update here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56128.