# CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

net migrating from java in selfstudy mode.(visual studio 2019 community & SqlServer 2017 64bit community edition installed).
I was following the instructions on this tutorial [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

When I executed the step of initial migration step I encountered this error when i run update-database I'm encountering this error. I know its related to database access/ configuration problem I'd really appreciate the correct way to provide it to Package Manager Console.

I've added the allow service to interact with desktop permission in the service of SQL server. As well as went through the settings of nuget Package manager settings including SQL server tools where I didnt find any setting to add of test connection.

> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while >attempting to open or create the physical file >'C:\Users\userRazorPagesMovieContext-f0053713-d1d4-4b1b-b07a->c77d6dfaf131.mdf'.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check >related errors.

Comment: The error is cristal clear: the user running the migrations doesn't have write permissions on the folder where you're creating the database. Give write permissions on the folder

Comment: Are you using localDB for your database? In that case the web server needs sufficient access rights to the deployment folder.

Comment: @Oscar Thank you it worked I went ahead and gave the Windows permission to write & it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution Thank you @Oscar for the solution. This is the problem originated due to visual studio's default behavior of storing the all projects in C drive and folders. Best solution Store the project files in other drives other than the OS.

Temporary solution: just rightclick -> property -> security give write permission

update: its said that the problem arises with a bug in Sql server 2017 which is fixed in update

> Cumulative Update 6 for SQL Server 2017.

@moderators plz mark this question as closed, thank you.

Comment: This is [SO]: when you can accept your own answer (there is a delay for self answered questions).

Answer (score 4):

The missing \ was caused by a bug from Sql Server. See this question for details: CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file. And download the update here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56128.